# celery-prometheus-exporter gives celery_workers count as 0

Tags: celery, airflow, monitoring, prometheus-node-exporter

trying to monitor active workers on airflow and have used following [exporter](https://github.com/zerok/celery-prometheus-exporter)
But in the metrics exposed always getting celery_workers as 0. Here is the metrics data:

```
python_info{implementation="CPython",major="2",minor="7",patchlevel="15+",version="2.7.15+"} 1.0
# HELP celery_workers Number of alive workers
# TYPE celery_workers gauge
celery_workers 0.0
# HELP celery_tasks Number of tasks per state
# TYPE celery_tasks gauge
celery_tasks{state="STARTED"} 0.0
celery_tasks{state="SUCCESS"} 6.0
celery_tasks{state="RECEIVED"} 0.0

Can anyone suggest what I am missing?. Thanks in advance
```